# Login page for a code-igniter invoice processing web-app doesn't run as expected

Tags: codeigniter, hosting

I have this invoice processing webapp created using code-igniter which runs well I local host. However, I uploaded it to 000wehost but it has issues. when I insert the right database password through the config/database.php file, it doesn’t run the login page which is the first page that should be loaded before the user does anything. but when I insert the wrong database password, the login page runs but obviously, the app doesn’t connect with the database so the login procedure cat take place successfully. I don’t know how to make the app work as intended. Am stuck. Please help me. I will appreciate your insight and help.